# Using 2 themes in Keynote'13

Tags: keynote, themes

Ok, so I've choose "white" theme while creating a presentation. Can I somehow add slides from black theme? Or can I change theme of my presentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can do it in Keynote 2013 as Apple has removed this feature with this version.

An idea that you could do is to make a new Keynote file with the secondary theme that you want, copy the slide, and then paste the slide into your presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you *can* change the theme of your Keynote presentation in Keynote '13:

1. Go to the **Presentation Setup Inspector** (View → Inspector → Presentation Setup).

   [image]
2. Click the **Presentation** tab.

   [image]
3. Click **Change Theme**.

   [image]
4. Select your new theme and click **Choose**.

   [image]

Comment: Yes, and this changes all the slides I already have to black. Won't do. The solution is how @unior117 wrote: new presentation and copy slides

Comment: @Uko I was more answering the second part to your question: "Or can I change theme of my presentation?"

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry if I was to harsh. The thing is that I thought that changing of theme won't change anything anyway, so I didn't include that in question. Thank you for your effort

Comment: @Uko No problem :) I know it wasn't the answer you were looking for, but I thought it would help those that might have searched for your second question.